# Freezing while attempting to handle larger numbers within a recursion

Tags: python

I've been trying to create a Python program that calculates the Grade of Service of a telecommunication network using the recursive Erlang B formula: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rxixp.jpg)

The program receives the traffic load and number of line services as input, generating said GoS as a probability. My issue is that when I am attempting to give a larger number e.g 30 for the line services and 5 for the traffic load, it freezes and shows no result. On the other hand, giving a lower line service number such as 10 manages to calculate said result. Is it perhaps related to memory leaks?

This is what I've written so far:

```
lines = int(input('Give number of service lines (s): '))
load = int(input('Give the number of the traffic load (a) : '))


def grade_of_service(s, a):
    if s == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        result = float((a * grade_of_service(s-1, a)/(s + a * grade_of_service(s-1, a))))
        print(result)
        return result


print(grade_of_service(lines, load))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works for me. Try removing the `print()` inside of the function?

Comment: The print() inside the function was just a placeholder, the overall code worked with e.g lines = 10 and load = 5, but for larger numbers, e.g lines = 30 and load =5, the issue was the results being re-calculated all the time like Jose mentioned.

Comment: I mentioned it because trying to print tons of data in a short amount of time can sometimes also make it seem like the program is stuck or frozen.

Comment: The reason I put the print inside the function was to test if there were any results at all, so technically I had the same issue even before that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursive function is exponential over `s`: Each recursive call multiplies by two the number of calls.

With `s = 30` you have in the line `2**30` calls, which are a lot.

Usually, the way to solve this kind of problems is iterating from the bottom up or storing the intermediate results in a table to avoid recalculating them all the time, but in this case you can solve it with a variable:

```py
lines = int(input('Give number of service lines (s): '))
load = int(input('Give the number of the traffic load (a) : '))


def grade_of_service(s, a):
    if s == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        previous_grade_of_service = grade_of_service(s-1, a)
        return float((a * previous_grade_of_service /(s + a * previous_grade_of_service)))


print(grade_of_service(lines, load))
```

**EDIT** Here's an example for the 'cached' version:

```py
lines = int(input('Give number of service lines (s): '))
load = int(input('Give the number of the traffic load (a) : '))

cache = [None] * (lines + 1)
cache[0] = 1
def cached_grade_of_service(s, a):
    cached = cache[s]
    if cached == None:
        cached = float((a * cached_grade_of_service(s-1, a)/(s + a * cached_grade_of_service(s-1, a))))
        cache[s] = cached
    return cached

print(cached_grade_of_service(lines, load))
```

Comment: @dimitris1821gr If you have accepted the answer why can't you upvote it?

Comment: I did, but it didn't display it due to my reputation being lower than 15.
Also, another question, is the cached answer the general approach for solving matters like these in the future, or can both methods be applied?

Comment: @dimitris1821gr it depends a lot on the problem and legibility. It's called [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). I tend to favor the "from the bottom up" approach, but it's not always possible and sometimes it hurts legibility a lot. E.g: Fibonacci turns out to be `unsigned prev = 1, curr = 1, tmp = 0; for (unsigned i = 2; i < limit; i++) tmp = prev, prev = curr, curr = prev + tmp; return curr;`